# Preserving the state of select lists between posts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I've got an admin page that has a bunch of select lists that I populate on the original Get request from a database like this:

```
<select asp-for="ProductID" asp-="@Model.ProductSelectListItems"></select>
```

The controller returns a ViewModel with an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that gets fed into the view and rendered as a select list. So far so good.

The issue what happens when there is an error on the page caught by validation. The controller checks ModelState and sends the view back so the user can fix the error:

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(vm);
```

... but the SelectListItems are no longer there. The ViewModel instance that was bound upon postback no longer has a value for the ProductSelectListItems  property. I know I could put in some code in the controller to rebuild the list from the DB if there is a ModelState error like this:

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        vm.ProductSelectListItems = GetFromDatabaseYetAgain();
        return View(vm);
    }
```

But that just looks messy. There must be a cleaner way to do it, right?
I tried a hidden field, which works great for simple types, but it didn't work for a complex type:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductSelectListItems"/>
```

In the bad old days of web forms all this stuff would just be stuffed into ViewState which I know had a lot of problems. But this is an intranet site and performance won't suffer from a few hundred extra bytes in a hidden field passing back and forth.

Is there an easy way to just let asp.net handle this?

Comment: Will performance suffer from a few extra queries to the database to populate the list? Remember that if you have added client-side validation (which you should) `ModelState` will rarely be invalid.

Comment: I don't think hitting the DB again will be a problem for performance but it is another line of code. What if there are 10 dropdowns in a complicated admin page? Is it really best practice to have code to reload them all in the event of a server side error?

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft [EF Core with Razor Pages tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-a-base-class-for-course-create-and-edit) you can see they create a `PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList` method and then call it inside both `OnGet` and `OnPost` if model state is invalid. In one of my projects I used a similar [`PopulateSelectLists`](https://github.com/Jimmys20/ptyxiaki/blob/e7fd573d1a0557677f5bf704d6365f13a0611a6e/ptyxiaki/Pages/Theses/Create.cshtml.cs#L151) method. There is no other "easy way to handle this".

The alternatives would be to add some kind of [State Management](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/state-management) (like the hidden form field you tried). But for your hypothetical scenario with 10 dropdowns in a complicated admin page, I don't think that saving 10 entire datasets in session cookies or hidden form fields/query strings would be an ideal solution either.

If hitting the database multiple times is a problem then better implement [memory caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-imemorycache) and load the data from cache.